# Not able to login the mediawiki api using jquery

Tags: jquery, api, mediawiki

I am unable to login to mediawiki using their api through jquery

I am using the following code to login to the mediawiki api

The same as [http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Example_login_code_in_JS_(using_JQuery)](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Example_login_code_in_JS_%28using_JQuery%29)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
function wiki_auth(login, pass, ref){
$.post('http://upgrade.vaniquotes.org/w.1.22/api.php?action=login&lgname=' + login + 
        '&lgpassword=' + pass + '&format=json', 

    function(data) {
        if(data.login.result == 'NeedToken') {
            $.post('http://upgrade.vaniquotes.org/w.1.22/api.php?action=login&lgname=' + login + 
                '&lgpassword=' + pass + '&lgtoken='+ data.login.token +'&format=json', 

            function(data) {
            if(!data.error){
               if (data.login.result == "Success") { 
                    document.location.href=ref; 
               } else {
                    console.log('Result is: '+ data.login.result);
               }
            } else {
               console.log('Error: ' + data.error);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Result is not: ' + data.login.result);
    }
    if(data.error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data.error);
    }

    var myresult = data.login.result;
});
}
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
wiki_auth('Test', 'test123', '/w.1.22/');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I debug, I can see that the first post request returns the token and the 'NeedToken' result.

After the second post request when I am supplying it with the token id, It again returns the same result NeedToken instead of a success message

This is what i can see in chrome debugger console

```
XHR finished loading: POST "http://upgrade.vaniquotes.org/w.1.22/api.php?action=login&lgname=Test&lgpassword=test123&format=json".
XHR finished loading: POST "http://upgrade.vaniquotes.org/w.1.22/api.php?action=login&lgname=Test&lgpassword=test123&lgtoken=a037a59d881bbc48ce54951d009284ce&format=json".
Result is: NeedToken
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems that need to be addressed:

First, you are attempting to do cross-site scripting. If this were allowed, it would be a huge security vulnerability. Thus, a web browser won't let you do this. That said, if this script is to be hosted on "upgrade.vaniquotes.org", you'll want to use a relative path to your API, not an absolute one.

Second,

lgname, lgpassword, and lgtoken are POST parameters. You're using the post method, but not posting any parameters. Only action and format are GET parameters. To do this, your code will need to be in the format of

```
$.post('/api.php?action=login&format=json', {lgname: login, lgpassword: password}, ...
```

Comment: I will be using relative urls, but am testing at the moment.I tried this. But it does not work out. I get the response as Need token for the second time as well

Comment: Rewrite to use $.post('/api.php?action=login&format=json', { lgname: login, lgpassword: password}, function(data) { ....